# Not going through each if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
package main;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TweetTester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String tweet= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a tweet:\n(Hashtags should be represented as #hashtags and mentions should be represented by @mentions)");
        int length = tweet.length();
        if (length<=140)
        {
            String[] splited = tweet.split("\\b+"); //split on space
            if(Arrays.asList(splited).contains("#"))
            {
                int index = tweet.indexOf("#");
                int count = 0;
                while (index != -1)
                {
                    count++;
                    tweet = tweet.substring(index + 1);
                    index = tweet.indexOf("#");
                }
                System.out.println("No of *#* in the input is : " + count);
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(splited).contains("@"))
            {
                int index = tweet.indexOf("@");
                int count2 = 0;
                while (index != -1)
                {
                    count2++;
                    tweet = tweet.substring(index + 1);
                    index = tweet.indexOf("@");
                }
                System.out.println("No of *@* in the input is : " + count2);
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(splited).contains("http://"))
            {
                int index = tweet.indexOf("http://");
                int count3 = 0;
                while (index != -1)
                {
                    count3++;
                    tweet = tweet.substring(index + 1);
                    index = tweet.indexOf("http://");
                }
                System.out.println("No of *http://* in the input is : " + count3);
            }
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (140 - length)+" Charcters Left\n"+"Tweet:\n"+tweet+"\nLength Correct"+ "number of #:"+count);
        }
        if (length>140 ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Excess Characters: "+(length-140));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not going through each of the if statements. Any Ideas

Comment: Inconsistent style makes the code unreadable and hard to understand.  That might be why you can't figure it out.  Run in a debugger and step through.  Should be easy to spot.

Comment: What was you input text value?

Comment: ok no luck any other ideas, the input is the JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Comment: Are you sure the condition your if blocks are testing for is true?

Comment: I am positive on that

Comment: I tried on my side and it's working that's why I asked about the value you entered in the input text

Comment: did you try more than one like @hashtags and #mentions in the same tweet

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably should use `\\s+` regexp:

```
String[] splited = tweet.split("\\s+"); //split on space
```

Second, in each if(){ ... } you **modify (truncate)** your original tweet string and lose some data.

For example when your tweet equals:

```
String tweet = "one @ two # # three # four";
```

your first if() removes the first part of origianl tweet string:

```
tweet = tweet.substring(index + 1);
```

and in second if() tweet will not have any `"@"` character.

Result for above tweet is:

```
No of *#* in the input is : 3
No of *@* in the input is : 0
```

Comment: but inside of the ifs is local variables modifying tweet not global, therefore should it not affect tweet.

Comment: You have only 1 tweet variable in main method. When you call: `tweet = tweet.substring(...)` you get some shorter substring and assign this substring to tweet - so tweet is now modified

Comment: If you want to have effect as quick as possible, you can add line `String copy = tweet;` in the beginning of each `if()`. Then you operate only on `copy` - this `copy` string is **local** in your `if`. But better approach is to use indexOf as proposed @Joop Eggen

Answer (score 0):

You change tweet. That is not needed as there is a String.indexOf(String sought, int startPos).
Better still don't-repeat-yourself:

```
public static int count(String sentence, String word) {
    int count = 0;
    int oldPos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int pos = sentence.indexOf(word, oldPos);
        if (pos == -1) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
        oldPos = pos + word.length();
    }
    return count;
}
```

The regex `"\\b"` is for word boundaries, and is problematic for `http://`.
In fact, why not simple count, and then test count != 0.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String tweet= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a tweet:\n"
        + "(Hashtags should be represented as #hashtags and mentions should be "
        + "represented by @mentions)");
    int length = tweet.length();
    if (length<=140)
    {
         int count = count(tweet, "#");
         if (count > 0) {
             System.out.println("No of *#* in the input is : " + count);
         }
         count = count(tweet, "@");
         if (count > 0) {
             System.out.println("No of *@* in the input is : " + count);
         }
         count = count(tweet, "http://");
         if (count > 0) {
             System.out.println("No of *http://* in the input is : " + count);
         }
    }
    else
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Excess Characters: " + (length-140));
    }
```

Comment: Also, whereas splitting on whitespace instead of on word boundaries would help the test for "http://" work, it wouldn't get all the way there, and it would break the (questionable) tests for "@" and "#".  This is because the code uses `List.contains(Object)`, which will test for exact matches (to the strings "@", "#", and "http://") whereas what is needed is to test each List *element* with `String.contains(CharSequence)`.

Comment: where would I incorporate this in the code. if needed modify original code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes "aaa @bbb" would yield "aaa", " @" (with space), "bbb". przemek hertel is right to use `"\\s+"`.

Comment: @Keeth extended the answer.

Comment: getting an error on int count = count(tweet,"#"); , count = count(tweet, "@"); , count = count(tweet, "http://");